# Unable to get user by email using Cloud Function for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using the Node.js Admin SDK within a Cloud Function for Firebase and I want to call the `admin.auth().getUserByEmail()` method.

Since I'm using a Cloud Function I read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk) that I only need to call `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` which you can see below I've done.

However, when I call the `getUserByEmail()` (only tested locally) I get the following error:
`'No Firebase project was found for the provided credential.'`

Here's my index.js

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest(function (req, resp) {
  var from = req.body.sender;
  admin.auth().getUserByEmail(from)
    .then(function (userRecord) {
      // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
      console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
    })
});
```

Has anyone got any experience of this and can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin sdk won't get proper config json if you are using localy(in google cloud functions emulator). You have to use your service account json obtained from firebase console.

But if you have deployed it, your method will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Anand - I thought that might be the problem so I quickly tried to use the non-cloud function config approach but I got a different error about trying to initialise 2 different projects. I'll try that approach again with a bit more care :-)

Comment: Check that link for initialising two apps.

Comment: Thanks Anand I've set it up using the non- Cloud Function approach now and all works great. Since I'm a Admin SDK noob I didn't know if I was doing something wrong when using the documented approach...it's definitely an issue with the local emulator.

Comment: Cloud functions are easy actually. Just the initialising part is tricky. If you use the service account way, it will work properly in both local and live. Once initialised admin sdk is just like your browser sdk. Anyways since you have setup without cloud functions, no probs :)

Comment: I love Cloud Functions but this local 'Gotcha' is something that I'll flag in the docs so that others might not waste so much time. It'll be service account initialisation every time for my future projects. Thanks for your confirmation :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi. I am currently facing a similar issue (starting to use cloud functions with firebase), and would like to know what this "proper config json" mentioned in the answer is. I am not doing anything locally.